# MS graph API cannot grant Application roles

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am not able to grant the Application role using graph API. Below is the code

**Code**

```
 IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientFactory.SpnAuthenticate(_configuration["ClientId"],
                                                                                           _configuration["ClientSecret"],
                                                                                           _configuration["TenantId"]);
            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication: app);
            Beta.GraphServiceClient graphClient = new Beta.GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            var appRoleAssignment = new Beta.AppRoleAssignment
            {
                AppRoleId = model.appRoleId,
                ResourceId = model.resourceId,
                ResourceDisplayName = "resourceDisplayName-value"

            };

            var respone = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals[model.servicePrincipalId].AppRoleAssignments
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(appRoleAssignment);
```

**Error**

```
Status Code: BadRequest
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Not a valid reference update.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: 9e94e7e1-b4bf-415e-8aee-7d6d199dbe1b
    date: 2020-04-26T06:43:59
ClientRequestId: 9e94e7e1-b4bf-415e-8aee-7d6d199dbe1b
```

App role assignment function properpties

```
appRoleId
creationTimestamp
PrincipalDisplayName 
principalId
principalDisplayName
resourceDisplayName
ResourceId
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the correct code?

Comment: Hmm, at least when I do these with PowerShell, the service principal id needed to be included in the URL _and_ the request body, requiring it to be specified twice to the cmdlet..

Comment: Added the Properties for appRoleAssignment graph client  function in the question. can you tell me what else need to be added

Comment: I fixed it by adding princpalId = Service Principal ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Thanks @juunas

Updated Code:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientFactory.SpnAuthenticate(_configuration["ClientId"],_configuration["ClientSecret"],_configuration["TenantId"]);

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication: app);
            Beta.GraphServiceClient graphClient = new Beta.GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            var appRoleAssignment = new Beta.AppRoleAssignment
            {
                AppRoleId = model.appRoleId,
                ResourceId = model.resourceId,
                ResourceDisplayName = "resourceDisplayName-value",
                PrincipalId = model.servicePrincipalId
            };

            var respone = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals[model.servicePrincipalId].AppRoleAssignments
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(appRoleAssignment);
```